# terraform index value inside format

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to join two strings together within a single line,
`aws_iam_policy.policy[*].arn` (which calls all "policy") and `data.external.run_script.result["arns"]`(which call a serie of strings) in the same string.

The first one doesnt works, but the second does

have tried different methods, with format beinf th closest to work `[format(aws_iam_policy.policy[*].arn, %s, data.external.run_script.result["arns"])]`, but it takes the whole first string as a literal, intead of calling all the policies.

the output looks like this

```
"aws_iam_policy.policy[*].arn, arn:aws:iam::030112431572:policy/works"
```

where it should be giving back something like this

```
"aws_iam_policy.policy[0].arn, aws_iam_policy.policy[1].arn, aws_iam_policy.policy[2].arn, arn:aws:iam::030112431572:policy/works"
```

** EDIT **

I've seem to be closer now with `[format("%s, %s", data.external.run_script.result["arns"], aws_iam_policy.policy[*].arn)]` , but the answer now shows as follows

```
"arn:aws:iam::030112431572:policy/works", ["arn:aws:iam::030112431572:policy/alsoworks"]): InvalidInput: ARN &quot;arn:aws:iam::030112431572:policy/works&quot;, [&quot;arn:aws:iam::030112431572:policy/alsoworks&quot;] is not valid.
```

it seems that aws_iam_policy.policy[*].arn is responding with brackets, is there any way of deleting them?

Comment: Not sure if this will work but can you try `[count.index]` instead of `[*]`?

Comment: it didnt work, but thanks anyway, im trying right now with something like this ```[format("%#v, %s", data.external.run_script.result["arns"], aws_iam_policy.policy[*].arn]``` without sucess also

Comment: How does `data.external.run_script.result["arns"]` look like?

Comment: ´´´"arn:aws:iam::030112431572:policy/works"´´´ exactly as this

Answer (score 1):

Try concat function

```
concat(aws_iam_policy.policy[*].arn, data.external.run_script.result["arns"])
```

This will create a list of both the lists.

Comment: Invalid value for "seqs" parameter: all arguments must be lists or tuples; got string.
This shit is hard, i've been 4 hours into it without sucess now

Comment: For a concat function to work, the values need to be a list. Try storing your data.external.run_script.result["arns"] in a value then concat it with other list.

Comment: IT WORKED, i had to use split but it workED THANKS GOD, its 1 am and im still working on this bullshit, thanks dude this is how i used it ```concat(aws_iam_policy.policy[*].arn, split(",", data.external.run_script.result["arns"]))```

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Answer (score 0):

i've managed to do it with concat and split, as `aws_iam_policy.policy[*].arn` is a list, so i had to find a way to make  `data.external.run_script.result["arns"` a list and join them.

The final code looks like this

```
concat(aws_iam_policy.policy[*].arn, split(",", data.external.run_script.result["arns"]))
```